# Codeigniter: how to get a filename of a file

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am a Codeigniter rookie and i am trying to get the file name of an uploaded image so that i can save it in the database.
 i have two models, homemodel deals with my database and the image_upload_model deals with image uploading.
Everything works fine except i dont know how to post the image filename to the database

**image_upload_model.php**

```
<?php

class Image_upload_model extends CI_Model {

    var $image_path;

    //constructor containing the image path
    function Image_upload_model() {

        $this->image_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../assets/img');
    }

    //uploading the file
    function do_upload() {

        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path' => $this->image_path
        );
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
    }
}
?>
```

**homemodel.php**

```
<?php

class homeModel extends CI_Model {

    //inserting into the table tenants
    function addTenants() {

        $this->load->model('Image_upload_model');

        $data = array(
            'Fname' => $this->input->post('Fname'),
            'Lname' => $this->input->post('Lname'),
            'contact' => $this->input->post('contact'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
            'img_url' => " "//the filename of the image should go here
        );

        $this->db->insert('tenants', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

The controller
**homecontroller.php**

```
<?php

class HomeController extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->model('homemodel');
        $this->load->model('Image_upload_model');

        if ($this->input->post('submit') == 'Submit') {

            $this->homemodel->addTenants();
            echo 'inserted';
            $this->Image_upload_model->do_upload();
            echo 'image uploaded';
        }
        $this->load->view('index.php');
    }
}
?>
```

any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you check the [File Updloading class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)?  It pretty much handles file upload.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get file name like this

```
  $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
  $file_name =   $upload_data['file_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

On a very high level, you need to restructure your code as follows:

(1) In your `HomeController`, upload the image first (`$this->Image_upload_model->do_upload()` and then update your database (`$this->homemodel->addTenants()`

(2) In your upload model, you need to invoke `$this->upload->data()` to get the information array that contains your file name (see CodeIgniter documentation).  You then have to get that file name and make it available to the HomeController and pass it to the `addTenants` function.

With this guidance, you should be able to modify your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Easy to get file name with `$this->upload->file_name`

based on function upload in `system/library/upload.php`

```
public $file_name               = "";
public function data()
{
    return array (
                    'file_name'         => $this->file_name,
                    'file_type'         => $this->file_type,
                    ...
                );
}
```