# Getting file name after uploading the file in CI

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I want to store file name in a database and file in a folder when I click on the button. File is successfully uploaded but I didn't get the file name.
Here is my view :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('home/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function do_upload()
    {

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $image_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../assets/pics');
        $config['upload_path'] = $image_path; //base_url('assets/pics'); //APPPATH . 'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
         $file_name =   $upload_data['file_name'];
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            echo 'error';
        }
        else
        {
            echo $file_name .' uploaded...';

        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: how to get a filename of a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684885/codeigniter-how-to-get-a-filename-of-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

In your success part of upload add variable `$file_data = $this-upload->data();`

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {

echo 'error';

} else {

$file_data = $this-upload->data();


echo $file_data['file_name'] .' uploaded...';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass input field name to the `do_upload()` method:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("userfile")) {
        echo 'error';
}
else {


     $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
     echo $upload_data['orig_name'];

     //OR pass to view
}
```